# React Native v0.60.0 Android run failing with linking issue

Tags: react-native

Build Details

> ```
>     buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
>     minSdkVersion = 16
>     compileSdkVersion = 28
>     targetSdkVersion = 28
>     supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
>     playServicesVersion="17.0.0"
> ```

Error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:738)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:591)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:529)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:484)
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.<clinit>(JSCExecutor.java:19)
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutorFactory.create(JSCExecutorFactory.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:949)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: I also encountered this problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258550/couldnt-find-dso-to-load-libhermes-executor-release-so