# couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-release.so

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

log:

```
    Time    Tag Message
    15:56:52.131    SoLoader    couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
    15:56:54.275    SoLoader    couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-release.so
```

android\app\build.gradle:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,
]
```

android\build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this error?

https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes

---

react-native info:

- OS: Windows 10
- CPU: (8) x64
- Node: 12.16.1
- Yarn: 1.22.4
- npm: 6.13.4
- Watchman: 20200604.181126.0
- Android Studio: Version  3.6.0.0
- react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
- react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1

---

try add :

android\app\build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2"
    }
}
```

error log:

```
    Time    Tag Message
    16:14:51.168    SoLoader    couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so result: 0
    16:14:57.928    SoLoader    couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-release.so result: 0
```

Comment: you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61695629/8079868

Comment: @MuhammadNuman  My configuration is the same as him, but it doesn't work

Comment: did you try configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2"
    }
}

Comment: ` com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2` doesn't work，

```
 16:14:51.168 SoLoader couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so result: 0
 16:14:57.928 SoLoader couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-release.so result: 0
```

Comment: Does your `android\app\build.gradle` include the Hermes aars [like in the official template](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/86cad7d69099baaaeae10ac7c0912a023101f257/template/android/app/build.gradle#L187-L188)? Are there other associated errors in `adb log`?